# How do you find the indefinite integral for $\int \frac1{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you find the indefinite integral for $\int \frac1{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} dx $ ?

According to the Apostol's Calculus Vol1 textbook this can be done by integration by substitution but not sure how.

Comment: Which substitution did you try?

Comment: A sum of squares may suggest a substitution.

Comment: @Workaholic This is a u-substitution question according to author, if I substitute $ u=x^2+1 $, $ x = \sqrt{u-1} $ and $ \frac{du}{dx}=2x $ in $ \int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} \frac{2x}{2x} dx $ I get
$$ \int \frac{1}{u^{3/2}} \frac1{2x} du = \frac1{2} \int \frac{1}{u^{3/2}\sqrt{u-1}} du = \frac1{2} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^3(u-1)}} du  $$
Using $ s=u^4-u $ and $ \frac{ds}{du}=4u^3-1 $ doesn't seem to get anywhere, so I've been trying something else.

Comment: @CloudIcarus There is an even better substitution you can make. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x=\tan{u}\implies dx=\sec^2{u}\,du$.

$$\therefore\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}\,dx=\int\frac{\sec^2{u}}{\left(\tan^2{u}+1\right)^{3/2}}\,du=\int\frac{\sec^2{u}}{\sec^3{u}}\,du=\int\cos{u}\,du=\sin{u}+C$$
Now, note that $u=\tan^{-1}x$. Therefore,
$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}\,dx=\sin(\tan^{-1}x)+C$$

As **@martycohen** mentioned below, one can simplify to
$$\sin(\tan^{-1}x)+C=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+C$$

Comment: Note that $\sin(\arctan(x)) = x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach.

Considering $$I=\int\frac{{dx}}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$ change variable $x=\sinh(y)$, $dx=\cosh(y)\,dy$ and get $$I=\int\text{sech}^2(y)\,dy=\tanh (y)+C$$ Now, back to $x$, $$\tanh (y)=\frac{\sinh(y)}{\cosh(y)}=\frac x {\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Differentiate the function $$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: That's not a "hint," that is basically giving the answer. But the question is "*how to find* the indefinite integral." Can you explain *how* the OP could have thought of that?